# convert parse.com file uri to string Android

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, uri

i have a file that i got back from parse.com and i am trying to get the string stored in that file to a textView. At the moment all i am getting is a url in my text view and not the string i need.

getting the parse file:

```
ParseFile file = message.getParseFile("file");
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(file.getUrl());

//passing it to another class
intent.setData(fileUri);
```

getting the file to display in textview

```
mDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageDisplay);

    Uri textUri = getIntent().getData();

   // i have tried this also [ File string = new File(textUri.toString()); ]

    String filePath = textUri.getEncodedPath(); 
    mDisplay.setText(filePath);
```

i have tried:-

1] to get the string bytes before passing string via intent

2] getting url and then converting to string

and 1 or 2 more methods. all are displaying the url and not the string, i feel the issue may lie in this line

```
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(file.getUrl());
```

but i am not sure.

Comment: getUrl in parse.com returns the url always, not the file path

Comment: How can I get the string instead of url?

Comment: do you want to get the file name or what? please make clear which string

Comment: In the file there are 2 parts one the key "file" second part the message which is a string

Comment: To access the file I have the url for file now I need the string to show in textview not the url for string

Comment: can you post the url you are retrieving

Comment: It says http://parsenet.com/ loads of numbers here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87824/discussion-between-aakash-and-smithyy).